# Starting a new Codelite project from subversion

Tags: svn, codelite

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to import a new project in Codelite from an SVN repo. The documentation on the Codelite website is lacking on this. How does one actually do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing project from Svn is no different from importing a project from the local file system.
First, checkout th sources from Svn ( you can either do it from your favorite Svn client or use codelite's Svn plugin) - note that codelite's Svn plugin requires you to install Svn command line tool

Once you have checked out the sources you have 2 options here:
1) if you have a .workspace file , just load it into codelite ( workspace -> open workspace )
2) if you don't have a workspace, create a new project (yes, project) from workspace -> new project 
Select the type of the project you want give it a name and click OK. Then right click on the project and select import files from directory, select the directory where you just checked out the sources and codelite will do the rest

EDIT:

See a screenshot of the SVN plugin, maybe it will help:

[image]

Eran

Comment: I could never figure out how to even get to Codelite's SVN plugin. The documentation on the website is outdated and sparse. This is on Mac, btw.

Comment: I have edited my answer by adding a screenshot of the svn plugin

Comment: I also updated (a bit) the svn plugin docs on the website http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Subversion

Comment: Thank you! The documentation looks much better now.